# Is it possible to communicate between a child and parent using file streams without pipes? C

Tags: c, pipe

Is it possible to write to a file stream from the child and read it from the parent without using pipes?

I have:

```
FILE *fp;
char *msg = "TEST MESSAGE";

if (fork() == 0) {
    fp = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    dup2(fileno(fp), STDOUT_FILENO);
    execlp("echo", "echo", msg, NULL);
}

fp = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
char buf[1000];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);
printf("received: %s\n", buf);
fclose(fp);
```

temp.txt is empty when i try to read from it in the parent process, but if i cat it after running the program it has the test message. I tried to flush and seek(0) fp but that doesn't work.

Comment: It is certainly possible to avoid using named pipes.  Why are you using a named pipe at all?

Comment: But other than the title of the question, there's really no reason to believe that `temp.txt` is a named pipe.  My guess is that it is a regular file and you're just confused by the race condition.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I suspect that all you need is to have the parent `wait` for the child before it tries to read the data.

Answer (score 1):

This can work in principle, but you have a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition): it is possible that your parent process reads the file before the child has gotten around to writing it.  Remember that they are executing in parallel.

But for instance, if you have the parent `waitpid` for the child before attempting to read the file, you should find it has the right contents.

There are many other possible ways to synchronize the two processes, so that the parent only reads after the child is known to have finished writing: file locks, semaphores, signals, etc, etc.